# combobox to change font in application

Tags: java, css, javafx

I want to add a combobox to change the font or the font size in my application. I have built both comboboxes but I don't know how I can change the font and font size of every label. If I set a default font in my css, can I somehow change it when I select a new font? I don't like the idea of adding a setFont(font, fontSize) to every label that I have now and in the future.

```
public class SettingsController
{
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> font;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Integer> fontSize;

    public void initialize()
    {
        ObservableList<String> fonts = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Font.getFamilies());
        font.setItems(fonts);
        List<Integer> fontSizeList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer fontSizeNumber = 8; fontSizeNumber < 15; fontSizeNumber++)
        {
            fontSizeList.add(fontSizeNumber);
        }
        ObservableList<Integer> fontSizes = FXCollections.observableArrayList(fontSizeList);
        fontSize.setItems(fontSizes);
        if (font.getItems().contains("Arial"))
        {
            font.getSelectionModel().select("Arial");
        }
        fontSize.getSelectionModel().select((Integer) 12);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the setting to be saved, you'll need to write to an external CSS file and load it when your application launches. But yes, you should set the font using CSS, not `setFont()`.

Comment: Would you tell me how I can change the font property in my css? For e.g. how would I change the font for .root { -fx-font-family: "Arial"; }

Comment: Just like that; simply change the font family.

Comment: If you're asking how to actually write it to an external CSS, that is a different question entirely and there are plenty of guides out there.